# How to center a cluster in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

Having a example graph like this:

```
digraph g{
    subgraph cluster_test{
        john;
        mike;
    }
    amy->john;
    jack->mike;
    jack->john;
    james->john;
}
```

How could the cluster_test subgraph be positioned so each other nodes are getting places around it.

Answer (score 1):

The [`fdp`](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dot.1.pdf) layout uses a "spring" model and may suit your needs better than the hierarchical graphs `dot` produces. It's the only other layout besides `dot` which supports clusters.